# Need help formatting array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a JavaScript array with the following format:

```js
[
    {
     "header": true,
     "id": "0",
     "name": "dairy",
   },
    {
     "category": "dairy",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSlje6ESGALGpckMhb7",
     "name": "milk",
   },
    {
     "category": "dairy",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSm9EpFg5DhW036aUle",
     "name": "cheese",
   },
    {
     "header": true,
     "id": "3",
     "name": "dessert",
   },
    {
     "category": "dessert",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSm9MLZkrnvtPySw5U6",
     "name": "cake",
   },
    {
     "category": "dessert",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSmAQ0rdDLrpz0TSPuD",
     "name": "pie",
   },
    {
     "header": true,
     "id": "6",
     "name": "fruit",
   },
    {
     "category": "fruit",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSlazVIGAKLakxAIa8G",
     "name": "apple",
   },
    {
     "category": "fruit",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSlb5GH6xZz-DpNVS22",
     "name": "pear",
   },
    {
     "category": "fruit",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSwWJldY1nxQrotyv-V",
     "name": "strawberry",
   },
    {
     "header": true,
     "id": "10",
     "name": "meat",
   },
    {
     "category": "meat",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSljXQzfXthJbOA54Ah",
     "name": "fish",
   },
    {
     "category": "meat",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSmA2-R9pOY8abAUyST",
     "name": "steak",
   },
    {
     "category": "meat",
     "header": false,
     "id": "-LSmAJ4J4gIfVQ8sgPDa",
     "name": "pork",
   },
 ]
```

What I am trying to do, is map through this array, and transform it to the following format:

```js
[
  {
    title: nameOfFirstHeader,
    data: items.slice(indexOfFirstHeader, indexOfSecondHeader),
  },
  {
    title: nameOfSecondHeader,
    data: items.slice(indexOfSecondHeader, indexOfThirdHeader),
  },
  {
    title: nameOfThirdHeader,
    data: items.slice(indexOfThirdHeader, indexOfFourthHeader),
  },...and so on
]
```

So basically there will be an object section for each 'header' that is found in the original array. Each object section data property will contain the items found between the first header and the second header, and so on, until there are no more headers. I really can't wrap my head around how I can do this. Here is a reference to the the module I am using: https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid#sectiongrid-example

Thanks!

Comment: @Craig voting is completely discretionary. Showing no attempt to solve one's own problem is a perfectly valid case as it is expected here as is a clear and concise problem statement

Comment: Can't explain the downvotes — that's up to community members to determine how they value the question — however, I'm a little confused what is meant by "namOfFirstHeader" and `items`.  I think it would be more worthwhile to demonstrate what the data should look like given the sample data.  The explanation is confusing because even the use of "header" is quoted, as if it can't be explained what it is

Comment: Agree with @vol7ron about the confusion

Comment: my understanding is that there is an array of data that should be nested and is not. if header is true then that should be a top level item and everything directly following in the array should be a child of that item, unless the next item has header set to true as well, in which case it is a top level item as well. Thus converting a flat structure into a nested one.

Comment: @Craig that makes more sense, I didn't invest enough time in trying to understand.  For some reason I was thinking he was working with `true` and `false` as the title. The wording and example could be improved so that the reader is doing less working to understand and more work to help.  I still suggest that he should list the expected case given the example and the format

Comment: Hi all, I will post a more concise code and what I have tried. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're trying to accomplish...

```
var grouped = items.reduce((acc,obj)=>{
   let {header, name} = obj;

   if (header) return [...acc, { title:name, data:[] }] // either first matching header or new match. Add fresh 'header' object
   if (!acc.length) return acc;        //not header and none have passed. Do nothing

   let allButLast = acc.slice(0, acc.length-1),
       lastElem = acc[acc.length-1];  // not a header, but there is an existing match. Add it to last match's data array

   return [
      ...allButLast, 
      {
         ...lastElem, 
         data:[...lastElem.data, obj]
      }
  ]
},[])
```

but it seems unreliable to trust the order of an array for this purpose. It would probably be more reliable to match by `isHeader.name === notHeader.category` to be less presumptive about the order of data you're iterating over. Like this...

```
var grouped = items.reduce((acc,obj)=>{
   let {header, name, category} = obj;

   if (header) return [...acc, { title:name, data:[] }];
   if (!acc.length) return acc;        

   return acc.map((elem)=>{
      if (elem.title !== category) return elem; 
      return {
        ...elem,
        data: [ ...elem.data, obj]
      };
   })
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks so much being able to understand my poorly worded question lol. This is exactly what I needed. I still can't wrap my head around exactly how you solved that.

Comment: No problem, I thought your pseudo code was pretty clear actually, though the explanation you’ve added provides additional clarity.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can probably do something like

```
const data = [];
let activeIndexForData = -1;

for(let i = 0; i < dataToSort.length -1; i++) {
   if(dataToSort[i].header) {
       activeIndexForData++;
   }

   if(data.length < activeIndexForData - 1) {
       data.push({ title: dataToSort[i].name, data@ []})
   }
   else {
      data[activeIndexForData].data.push({ title: dataToSort[i].name, data: [])
   }
}
```